# In Fat Free Framework, how can I differentiate Cached Value vs. Array in config.ini?

Tags: php, arrays, caching, fat-free-framework

I have seen the [example posted](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/f3-framework/Rw5VNaaf6js/-sfBCPGy5igJ) by the author of FatFree Framework on setting cache values in routes and framework variables:

```
[globals]
foo=bar,86400 // variable cached for 24 hours

[routes]
GET /foo=Bar->baz,3600 // route cached for 1 hour
```

But in the [Fat Free Framework documentation](http://fatfreeframework.com/framework-variables#configuration-files), we have this example to set arrays

```
; this is also an array
items=7,8,9
; array with mixed elements
mix="this",123.45,FALSE
```

So, my question is, how can I differentiate if I want a value cached or Arrayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comma separated values in the `[globals]` section indicate arrays *only*.

It looks like @bcosca mistakenly wrote his comment. The caching syntax for globals cannot work with the current codebase (internally the `set` method is called with 2 arguments only).

To make things clear, here's the meaning of commas for both sections:

```
[globals]
foo=bar,86400 //define an array

[routes]
GET /foo=Bar->baz,3600 //cache route for 1h
GET /foo=Bar->baz,0,56 //limits bandwith to 56 kps
```

In other words, the previous configuration file is equivalent to:

```
$f3->set('foo',array('bar',86400));
$f3->route('GET /foo','Bar->baz',3600);
$f3->route('GET /foo','Bar->baz',0,56);
```

Comment: oy! too bad :( Thanks for the clarification.